# Using EF Model Entities in Winforms UI

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am using Entity Framework code first in a test project. I have distributed code in different layers as below

**Model Layer**

This layer is reference in all other layers/projects

```
namespace Model
{
   Public class Sample
   {
      Public string Name

      [ForeignKey("Category")]
      public int CatrgoryId

      Public Category Category
   }
}
```

**DAL**

```
namespace DAL
{
   public class SampleContext:DbContext
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

In DAL I only have the context class and migrations

**BLL**

```
namespace BLL
{
   public class SampleBLL
   {
       public List<Sample> GetAll()
       {
          retrn new SampleContext().Samples().ToList()
       }
   }
}
```

**UI**

```
namespace UI
{
   public class UIHelper
   {
      public List<Sample> GetSamples()
      {
         return new SampleBLL().GetAll();
      }

   }
}
```

It does not seem practical to use EF entity model objects in UI as they might have navigation properties and cannot be directly bound to controls like DataGridView because in that case the datagridview will have both the CategoryId and Category columns while I need to display the Category Name as Category eg `DataGridView.DataSource = new SampleBLL().GetAll()`
One solution that I could think of is to use ViewModel classes and manually map the entity model objects to viewmodel objects in BLL and return viewmodel objects to UI, But, introducing a new layer ViewModel would mean replicating all my Model objects with minor changes.

Forexmple the view model for above sample model would

```
namespace Model
{
   Public class Sample
   {
      Public string Name

      public int CatrgoryId

      public string CategoryName
   }
}
```

Is the viewmodel layer only option I have or there is an other efficient way to consume the Entity Models directly in UI.

Answer (score 1):

It is a very bad idea to use Entity Models directly in UI, mainly because of the issues you've exposed. More importantly, you're currently only retrieving data and displaying it "as is", but the slightest change in UI affects DB, and vice-versa. Any more complexe logic would be very troublesome to implement, AFAIK

At work, we use a **Transport** namespace to store classes corresponding to our entities and **assemblers methods** to convert entities to transport classes once we're done with retrieval logic. This way we're separating model from controller, and can safely manipulate data without any risk of unwantingly affecting the database.

Comment: Tnx. So you are recommending to use ViewModels (or Transport classes) to get data to and from UI to BLL. That would mean keeping almost identical entities in both Model layer as well as transport layer

Comment: If you're using EntityFramework, you might be able to generate your entities automatically. Yes, it is recommended to do so. Plus side is, you can code transport classes that format custom data ready for the view, (like "ViewModel" is suggesting) and not exclusively rely on what is stored in the database.